# How can I exit from a recursive function?

Tags: c#, recursion

I am working on a program which works with a recursive function.

My problem is when the work of the recursive function is complete, and control is transferred to next function, it returns back to recursive function after completing work of next function.

I need some code which could force from control being transferred back to function. I don't want to exit my program.

```
public void function1(a, num)
{
  if(a >= num)
  {
    if(a > num)
      function1(a, num);
    else if(a == num)
    {
      a++;
      function1(a, num)
    }
  }
  else
    function2(a, num)
}

public void function2(a, num)
{
  //print result;
}
```

Every time I'm calling `function1`, I'm performing some changes in variables `a` and `num`. But the problem is that at certain condition when `function2` is called control is passed to `function1` again. Could you provide me with some code to prevent that? It is a section of a time table generator I'm designing.

Comment: for the case when initially `a > num`, your recursion won't stop, because you are not changing anything between recursion steps. try to trace the code yourself for say a = 1, num = 0.

Answer (score 3):

> Put a ***return*** whenever you want to return to base

Answer (score 2):

This version of your function works exactly the same.

```
public void function1(a, num)
{
    if (a < num)
    {
        function2(a, num);
    }
    else
    {
        function1((a > num) ? a : a + 1, num);
    }
}

public void function2(a, num)
{
    //print result;
}
```

Just for your information:
if `a` is passed, that is greater than `num`, then the function will recurse ininitely, with efective call of the same argument list `function1(a, num)`, thus it'll never return resulting in hangup and eventually a stack overflow at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to:

```
public void function1(a,num)
{
    if(a>num)
     {
       //Increment num or decrease a here, otherwise the recursion never ends
       function1(a,num);
       return; //Each time the method does a recursion, it stops to execute itself with
       // a new set of arguments, but when one of them decide it's over, all the 
       // instances of the method will resume one by one, so if you don't return, 
       // it executes the rest of function1.
     }
    else if(a==num) 
     {
       a++; //You probably don't want to do that, this a==num case should be merged
       // with a>num. Can you see why?
       function1(a,num)
       return;
     }
    else
       function2(a,num)
}

public void function2(a,num)
{
 //print result;
}
```

Comment: I may have missed something, but how do those `return` statements change anything?  Without them, flow will jump over all of the `else` blocks and terminate at the end of the function.

Comment: This is again endless recursion if `a > num` initially -- though it matches the OP's code logic.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food yes good point, although he seems to be learning to I showed the usual practice.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the code would be simpler if you just performed a straight loop.

```
while (a <= num)
{
   function2(a, num);
   a++;
}
```